# Last line of typewriter script repeating before moving onto next scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a function in Unity that, on the press of a button, displays a line of text on the screen character by character and on the final button press moves onto the next scene. I have four lines of text which work, but on the final button press the fourth line repeats itself before moving onto the next scene.

```
    public void StartTypewriter()
    {
        start = true;
        сharIndex = 0;
        time = 0f;
    }

    public void SkipTypewriter(){
        сharIndex = ORIGINAL_TEXT.Length - 1;
    }

    public void NextString()
    {
        start = true;
        сharIndex = 0;
        time = 0f;
        if (index_of_string + 1 < MultiStrings.Length)
        { 
            index_of_string++;
        }
        else
        {
            SkipButton.onClick.AddListener(NextScene);
        }
        ORIGINAL_TEXT = MultiStrings[index_of_string];
    }

    public void NextScene()
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Console Loading...");
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Scenes/Game");
    }
```

When running over the function logically in my head, it should work as when the if detects that the index is five the only thing it should do is the NextScene function, but maybe there's an issue with my numbering that I'm not picking up on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the problem. Turns out the listener was being added on one click and then the second click took us to the scene. So I got rid of the NextScene method and re-engineered the NextString Function like so:

```
public void NextString()
{
    start = true;
    сharIndex = 0;
    time = 0f;
    if (index_of_string + 1 < MultiStrings.Length)
    {            
        index_of_string++;
    }
    else if (index_of_string + 1 == MultiStrings.Length)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Console Loading...");
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Game", LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
    ORIGINAL_TEXT = MultiStrings[index_of_string];
}
```

Now the last line of text displays in the typewriter style and on the next button press the previous scenes close and the fresh scene loads in its place.